# Ruby regex search

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm working on a script to search through a block of HTML text for `%{}` signs to replace them with dynamic variables.

For some reason my regex is not working.

```
str = "<p>%{urgent_personal_confidential}</p>"

regex = /^%\{(.*)\}/
puts str.match(regex)
```

I am sure its something simple... any ideas on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ruby already has that feature [built-in into String](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001127).

```
"The quick brown %{animal1} jumps over the lazy %{animal2}" % { :animal1 => "fox", :animal2 => "dog"  }
```

The result is

```
"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm misinterpreting, but can't you just Ruby's built-in string interpolation?

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > str = "<p>%{urgent_personal_confidential}</p>"
=> "<p>%{urgent_personal_confidential}</p>" 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > str % { :urgent_personal_confidential => "test" }
 => "<p>test</p>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your text isn't at the start of the string or immediately after a new line character you shouldn't use a start-of-line anchor (`^`):

```
regex = /%\{(.*)\}/
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/aDtVx)

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my issue!!! I will make sure to mark it as the answer once I can :)

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by the initial caret `^`, which stands for "beginning of line". If you remove it, it should match.